# Execute a function when pressing a button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am quite new to programming, and have met a problem.

I really want to run this function, when I press a button. Here is the function that I want to run:

```
function generateTip() {
    var tip = tipsList[generateNumber()];
    var tipElement = document.querySelector('.js-tip');

    tipElement.innerHTML = tip;
}
```

Alright, I want to run this function, when pressing a button, and here is the code for my jQuery button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
      //run function here 
    });
});
```

It doesn't have to be jQuery, I just thought that would be easier. I would be very grateful if somebody would help and explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your HTML, you can use the `onclick` event handler to call a function when the button is clicked, using vanilla javascript. Like so:

```
<button onclick="generateTip()">button text</button>
```

If you want a solution using jQuery and your current code, all you have to do is call the `generateTip()` function inside the `$('button').click` wrapper:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
        generateTip(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't think it would be this easy!

Answer (score 0):

You're already there?

JQUERY Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('button').click(function() {
          generateTip();
      }); 
    });

    function generateTip() {
    var tip = tipsList[generateNumber()];
    var tipElement = document.querySelector('.js-tip');

    tipElement.innerHTML = tip;
    }
</script>
```

or by onclick only in the actual HTML and a script above:

```
<script>
function generateTip() {
var tip = tipsList[generateNumber()];
var tipElement = document.querySelector('.js-tip');

tipElement.innerHTML = tip;
</script>
```

Then in your HTML something like this

```
<input type="button" name"button" onclick="generateTip()";
```

Comment: Thanks for the various explanations, it works now. Far easier than I thought, wish I could upvote twice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To execute the function `generateTip()` on click, put this in your button code:

```
<input type="button" name="any" onclick="generateTip()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a .js file with this code:

```
function generateTip() {
var tip = tipsList[generateNumber()];
var tipElement = document.querySelector('.js-tip');
tipElement.innerHTML = tip;
}
```

You can then attach it to an HTML element like so:

```
<button onclick="generateTip()"> Button </button>
```

Hope that helps